# bootstrap table filter with checkbox

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I adjusted the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/16bmcr6d/4/

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

(function ($) {

    $('#filter').keyup(function () {

        var rex = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'i');
        $('.searchable tr').hide();
        $('.searchable tr').filter(function () {
            return rex.test($(this).text());
        }).show();

    })

}(jQuery));

});
```

How can I adjust it further in order to have all balances hidden once the checkbox is checked?

```
<label><input id="filter2" type="checkbox" checked="">Filter zero balances</label>
```

Also how can I store this value so the next time i load the page the checkbox is still checked?

In the example when the checkbox is checkd only Pound and Georgian Liari should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjusted your fiddle to give you an idea on how to do this:

[updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16bmcr6d/5/)

What the `filter` - function basically does is return only DOM - elements where the passed anonymous-function returns `true`, so in this case, you only need to provide a fitting function, for example:

`return $(this).find('td').eq(3).text() !== "0"`

By using `.find('td').eq(3)` I just select the `td`-element where the balance is stored, which is the fourth `td` in your table-row (`.eq` is zero-index based)

The whole code that gets executed when a `change` - event is triggered on the checkbox:

```
$('#filter2').on('change', function(){

    if(this.checked){
        $('.searchable tr').hide();
        $('.searchable tr').filter(function() {
            return $(this).find('td').eq(3).text() !== "0"
        }).show();
    }else{
        $('.searchable tr').show();
    }            

});
```

There are several ways to keep the state of the checkbox over various sessions, you could use [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) or something like [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) for example.

Comment: thank you! Works like I imagined it! Will work now on the cookie saving option (or localStorage).